# Google script for sending an email on a specific date, based on a cell value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

my knowledge of scripts is very basic. I'm trying to set up something that sends an email based on if the date in cell A3 is the same as today. I've set up a trigger to run daily to test but so far isn't working.

Here's the code:

```
    function emailAlert() {
  // today's date information
  var today = new Date();

  // getting data from spreadsheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Master');
  var range = sheet.getRange(1,3); 
  var data = range.getValue();

  if(data == today){

   MailApp.sendEmail('joey@kukoon.com','Test','Test')

  }
}
```

Could the date created in 'new Date' be in a different format?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out - the format was indeed incorrect for the 'new Date' - this included the current time (hours minutes), whereas the date in the sheet had the time at 00:00:00.

To fix this I input today.sethours to set the date at 00:00:00

```
function emailAlert() {
  // today's date information
  var today = new Date();
  today.setHours(0,0,0,0);
```